# If you wrote a C program with no pointers

Tags: c, pointers

If you wrote a C program with no pointers then does that mean that there is an absolute limit to how much memory the program can consume? If not, then what are other ways in which you could consume more memory than possible given the amount/type of variables in your code?

Also, how much memory does a pointer itself use?

**--EDIT--**

I see this come up a lot in the answers

> You are limited to stack size if you don't use dynamic allocation

Does this mean that if you have dynamic allocation the system/compiler will increase/decrease your stack as you go?

**--EDIT #2**

When I said "absolute limit to how much memory...", obviously programs with pointers don't get unlimited memory (but how sweet would that be?), but what I meant was, is the amount of memory the program can consume quantifiable as a finite number, or are there other ways for memory to continue growing beyond just the amount allocated for variables.

@djechlin and @wallyk pointed out that recursion could cause memory to increase dynamically.

Apparently it seems possible to create a program that's memory usage is limited by it's architecture, but it would have to be a fairly simple program to achieve this.

Thanks for all of the great answers and enthusiasm!

Comment: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(pointer));`

Comment: You are limited to stack size if you don't use dynamic allocation (allocating memory with `malloc` and assigning it to a pointer)

Comment: Define "memory". One could always treat a file as a ticker tape.

Comment: Also, you can't use more memory than possible... that's impossible

Comment: @user2864740 Valid point, but you can presume he probably means the memory that the compiler/system allocates his program for internal use.

Comment: Even with pointers there is a limit to how much memory your program can consume. There always is some limit to the available memory. I think you should rephrase your question to give more details about what you want to do or know.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: You can also use global variables. `char buffer[1024*1024*1024];` gives you about a gigabyte to play with.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Many compilers fail when given globals that big

Comment: @MooingDuck: Many compilers don't fail.  The limits for zero-initialized globals are sometimes looser.

Comment: Also, how do library calls (OS) factor into this?  There could be operating system calls that take no pointers but allocate more memory.  Actually, malloc itself can do that.

Comment: @DietrichEpp But, if we don't worship the devil; we won't be using global variables for such things.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: Let's keep subjective assessments out of this, there are legitimate use cases for large globals.

Comment: @DietrichEpp, please, name me a few (not trying to sound condescending, I actually am interested) because I've always been told they are extremely bad practice unless for things like mutexes or atomics.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: This kind of thing happens all the time in scientific computing, where you write a program to guide large chunks of data through a fixed pipeline.  Declare a few globals to hold your large matrices or what-have-you.  But the question is about facts, not assertions of taste (or devil-worship).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you write a program without dynamically allocating any memory (completely feasible and very common) but you will be limited to the stack size allocated to your program by your compiler and/or environment.

If you want to use more memory than available to you via the stack and don't want to use dynamic memory (see *insanity*) you could store variables and such in a temporary file and write/read to it as if it were a buffer in memory. The only issue with this is that if you ***really*** don't want to use pointers you can't actually open a file! (in a cross-platform, standards-adhering; good-programmer way) The C standard library function `fopen` returns a `FILE*` for use with file operation functions.

Oh, and to answer your question of how big a pointer is:

It depends.

On most generic operating systems 32-bit systems will have 32-bit pointers (4 bytes) and 64-bit systems will have 64-bit pointers (8 bytes)

You could always find out how big they are on your system by writing a little test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(void*));
    return 0;
}
```

**--EDIT--**

Dynamic memory management uses something other than stack space called the 'heap'. The heap can be dynamically allocated to any size necessary (limited by system parameters) but all memory allocated on the heap must be explicitly deallocated using call pairs of `malloc`/`free` so the programmer is given more responsibility with dynamic memory management, but also more possibility of screwing up with things like accessing freed memory and dangling pointers.

This is on the of the greatest things that newer C programmers get caught up with. (usually non-simple `malloc`s like dynamic 3D arrays and such)

Answer (score 2):

This program will fail on most computers, provided it is not optimized.  But even with optimizations, it is not hard to adjust it to fail.

```
static char buffer [1000000000];

int main (void)
{
    return main ();
}
```

If this succeeds in loading, then it will exhaust stack space.  There is no absolute limit to how much stack the program can use.

In general, a pointer uses the amount of memory needed to hold an address.  There are some architectural anomalies (especially with the early x86 architecture), but 16 bit machines tended to have 16 bit addresses; 32 bits for 32 bit machines, and 64 bits for 64 bit architectures.  There is no hard-and-fast rule that the data bus size be the same as the address bus size, but it tends to work that way.

The major historical exception is the 8088 through 80286 in "real mode".  Those used 32 bit addresses to form a 20 bit physical address even though the registers were all 16-bit.

Comment: If the compiler implements tail recursion optimization it might not use stack space

Comment: @MattMcNabb:  hence my comment about tweaking the program to prevent optimization.

Answer (score 1):

A function can call itself, and add that much memory to the stack. This can happen arbitrarily many times, up to memory exhaustion.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use pointers, the only thing that can grow with your program is the "stack", which is were local variables are stored.  Most systems do not have a method to detect when the stack overflows, so this is not a recommended way of using large amounts of data. Also, your algorithms would have to be "stack" oriented (see the Lisp or Forth programming languages).

The way you go down the stack is to make function calls, and the way up the stack is function returns. The stack size is determined by the operating system. When you run off the end of the stack, you either crash immediately, or start corrupting other memory.

The size of a pointer is based on the machine address size. On x86 machines, it is 4 bytes for 32-bit mode and 8 bytes for 64-bit mode.  There used to be `near` and `far` pointers in the days of 16-bit mode, which was 2 decades ago.

On other processors (such as a 8051 microcontroller), they usually support several different addresses spaces, so pointers can be 1 byte (`idata`), 2 bytes (`xdata`) or 3 bytes (generic pointer), and you can have a program that uses pointers of all 3 types.